# Laravel error 500 (undefined variable 'e') after adding new route?

Tags: laravel, error-handling, routes

I've just been working on an old project of mine, where I basically had to add one new page and link to it. Nothing too difficult, and locally everything works fine.
Only, after transferring my modifications to the server, the route refuses to work, erroring out in an error 500.
I've turned on the debugging and added a try/catch to capture the error, but I can't make sense of what could be the exact source of the error.

Index.php:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

try {
    $response = $kernel->handle(
        $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
    );

    $response->send();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    echo dd($e);
}
```

Exception:

```
ErrorException {#155 ▼
  #message: "Undefined variable: e"
  #code: 0
  #file: "/data/sites/web/umbrellaservicesbe/website/app/Exceptions/Handler.php"
  #line: 62
  #severity: E_NOTICE
  trace: {▼
    /data/sites/web/umbrellaservicesbe/website/app/Exceptions/Handler.php:62 {▼
      › 
      ›     return parent::render($request, $e);
      › }
      arguments: {▼
        $level: 8
        $message: "Undefined variable: e"
        $file: "/data/sites/web/umbrellaservicesbe/website/app/Exceptions/Handler.php"
        $line: 62
        $context: array:2 [ …2]
      }
    }
    /data/sites/web/umbrellaservicesbe/website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:326 {▼
      › {
      ›     return $this->app[ExceptionHandler::class]->render($request, $e);
      › }
      arguments: {▼
        $request: Request {#38 …}
        $exception: ErrorException {#160 …}
      }
    }
    /data/sites/web/umbrellaservicesbe/website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:120 {▼
      › 
      ›     $response = $this->renderException($request, $e);
      › } catch (Throwable $e) {
      arguments: {▼
        $request: Request {#38 …}
        $e: ErrorException {#160 …}
      }
    }
    /data/sites/web/umbrellaservicesbe/website/public/index.php:54 {▼
      ›     $response = $kernel->handle(
      › \t\t$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
      › \t);
      arguments: {▼
        $request: Request {#38 …}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Like I said, locally my route works just fine. Anyone has any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: Can you show `/data/sites/web/umbrellaservicesbe/website/app/Exceptions/Handler.php`? it seems the error occurs there.

Comment: go to handler at line 62 and look

Comment: just FYI you can use
`dd($e);`
instead
`echo "<pre>";
    echo $e;
    echo "</pre>";`

Comment: By default, and unless you modified `Handler.php`, it doesn't contain `$e`. All `Exception` instances are referenced by `$exception` in that file, so double check that. (Might not be true for older versions of Laravel, but version wasn't provided)

Comment: It does look like it dies in framework code, try deleting vendor rerunning `composer install` in case something got corrupted.

Comment: @Jerodev Handler.php line 62 is:  return parent::render($request, $e); I'm not entirely sure what could be going wrong for this to fail. All I've done is added a new blade template, and a route linking to it, with a function in my PageHandler returning the view..

Comment: @apokryfos I have tried that, but even then I still get the same error.

Comment: Check all your Controllers and Models file names and folder names and namespaces whether you have declared starting with small letter. it can cause problem on server although it work in local

Answer (score 0):

I've found the source of my problem.
In my /app/Exceptions/Handler.php, for some reason I had the following line crashing:

```
return parent::render($request, $e);
```

Because the parameter in question was actually $exception instead. Not sure how that happened.

After fixing that I got a clear indication of why my newly added route wasn't working: apparently the controller I had modified was not written correctly to the server. After reuploading this file everything worked fine.